# LookUps and callbacks

Tags: javascript, windows, mobile, callback

I'm having an issue with windows mobile 6.5 and the standard IE that comes with it and a web page that I developed.
In this web I have lookups, that I manage with a callback, like this:

```
window.callbackFunc = VendorLookUp_callback;
window.open('LookUpVendor.aspx?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query));
```

So, I define a callback function for the lookup and open it. Then, in the lookup code:

```
window.parent.opener.callbackFunc(document.getElementById('invItmSelected').value);
window.close();
```

This, doesnt work on Windows Mobile environment, the lookup opens but, then, the callback function doesnt work because:

```
window.parent.opener = undefined
```

So, I can't get to the callback function. I tryied with:

```
window.parent.opener
window.top.opener
window.opener
window.parent
window.top
```

But, I still can´t get it to work.

This web works fine with the desktop versions of IE9, IE10, Firefox and Chrome. I also tested this on Firefox and Dolphin for Android, and works to.

**EDIT:** I tryied using Opera on the same mobile and it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clutching at straws but can you access it directly on the `window` object? i.e. `window.callbackFunc`. I can't imagine any reason why this would work but mobile windows IE is ridiculous.

Comment: Yeah, it kinda sucks...

Comment: And if you try `window.prototype.callbackFunc = VendorLookUp_callback;` with `window.opener.callbackFunc` ?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to hold reference to your new lookup window. Watch the lookup window to see if its loaded properly and then execute your call back

```
var lookupwin = window.open('LookUpVendor.aspx?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query));
lookupInt = window.setInterval(function(){
  //check if your lookup window is loaded
  if(lookupwin.document.getElementById("#some_element_to_check")){ //look for an element or something
    //if things look good execute your callback
    VendorLookUp_callback();
    window.clearInterval(lookupInt);
  }
}, 0);
```